# Finding the highest sum of a string in a list

Tags: python

In this task, we creating a function called highsum.  It looks at a list of strings and sums up all the numerical characters. We then return the location of the element of the list with the highest value.

For example given list  highestSum([“jx72i9r”, “9ch37@r2”, “8rgku3op8”]).
We then must find [17, 21,19] which is all the numerical values added up. Because 21 is the highest value we need the function to return 1 because that is the location of 9ch37@r2 in the list.

This is what I have so far:-

```
     def highestSum(stringList):
        number= 0
        for xinlist in stringList:
           print(xinlist)
           for yoflist in xinlist:
               print (yoflist)
               if yoflist in "1234567890":
                  number+=int(yoflist)
        print(number)
```

The first for loop cycles through each element while the second for loop cycles through each character in the elements. My accumulator variable work but the problem is I don't know how to let it know when it moves on to a new element.

Another example `highestSum([“90gw1xy3”, “12432”, “hfkvbd2”, “*&hdj!4”])`
this would return 0 as it as the highest sum of digit characters.

Comment: I took maths, and know that 7+2+9 = 18, not 17. Or am I dumb

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: @BuddyBob you are right the last value was supposed to be 8 but I was rushing typing this cause this is due tonight.

Comment: @TomServo I am a new coder. I thought debugging was when we go through the code and fix errors.

Comment: @neal Debugging starts with  *you*.  Debugging is when *you* use a debugger to trace through your own code and learn why it's not working as expected.  It works "as coded," by definition.  You use a debugger to turn "as coded" into "as expected."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Homemade version**

Basically, we gather turn each element in the given list to there digits sum. So like `[18,21,19]`. Then pair this with original list using `zip()`. Then use `.index()` in order to get the corresponding index.

---

*hilarious one-liner*

```
def highestSum(stringList):
    return stringList.index({k:v for k,v in zip([sum(list(map(int,[character for character in stringEx if character.isdigit()]))) for stringEx in stringList],stringList)}[max(summed)])
```

*List comprehension & dict comprehension*

```
def highestSum(stringList):
    summed = [sum(list(map(int,[character for character in stringEx if character.isdigit()]))) for stringEx in stringList]
    highest = max(summed)
    pair = {k:v for k,v in zip(summed,stringList)}
    return stringList.index(pair[highest])
print(highestSum(["jx72i9r", "9ch37@r2", "8rgku3op8"]))
```

*Easier to understand for the human eye.*

```
def highestSum(stringList):
    summed = []
    for stringEx in stringList:
        gathered = []
        for character in stringEx:
            if character.isdigit():
                gathered.append(character)
        gathered = sum(list(map(int,gathered)))
        summed.append(gathered)
    highest = max(summed)
    pair = {}
    for k,v in zip(summed,stringList):
        pair[k] = v
    return stringList.index(pair[highest])

print(highestSum(["jx72i9r", "9ch37@r2", "8rgku3op8"]))
```

output

```
1
```

Comment: I put your code into idle and ran it. For some reason whenever I run it, it outputs 0 but when I save the file the shell outputs 1. I don't understand what is going on

Comment: hmm, that's something to do with your IDE. shouldn't happen normaly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to take soo, cause everyone code is doing the same thing and there is no way everyone one code is wrong.

Comment: @neal, pleace accept this post if it has helped.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code. Look at this solution. You need a condition to for the highest number in the list and a variable to keep track of its index. See solution below:

```
def highestSum(stringList):
     index = 0            
     highestValue = 0  
     for xinlist in stringList:
         number= 0  
         for yoflist in xinlist:
             if yoflist in "1234567890":
                 number+=int(yoflist)

         if number > highestValue:
             index = stringList.index(xinlist)
             highestValue = number
     print(index)

stringList = ['jx72i9r', '9ch37@r2', '8rgku3op8']
highestSum(stringList)
```

Comment: Hi @neal, there were some indention problems at the end, I edited that and tested the code again. I think it's returning the correct index based on the highest value on the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use list comprehension, maybe it's difficult to read.

code:

```
x = ["jx72i9r", "9ch37@r2", "8rgku3op8"]
x_to_int = [sum([int(char) for char in s if char.isdigit()]) for s in x]
print(x_to_int.index(max(x_to_int)))
```

result:

```
1
```

Comment: They need to return the index of 21, not 21 itself

Comment: I believe this is the shortest!

Comment: na man, mine is the shortest lmao. #Disclaimer, shortest doesn't matter. Cleanliness, readability and speed of code does matter. Making code shorter does not equal Lighting McQueen.

Comment: @BuddyBob if i change it to one-liner `print([sum([int(char) for char in s if char.isdigit()]) for s in x].index(max([sum([int(char) for char in s if char.isdigit()]) for s in x])))`,it use 142 characters.Your one-liner answer use 173 characters.Just kidding.

Comment: Sure, we both have different approaches. You use looping, I use `zip()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def highestSum(stringList):
    res = list()
    for xinlist in stringList:
        number = 0
        for yoflist in xinlist:
            if yoflist in "1234567890":
                number += int(yoflist)
        res.append(number)

    # find the max position form the accumulator
    maxNumPos = 0
    for i in range(len(res)):
        if res[i] > res[maxNumPos]:
            maxNumPos = i

    print(maxNumPos)


highestSum(['90gw1xy3', '12432', 'hfkvbd2', '*&hdj!4'])
```